# Javascript alert() issue

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm new in javascript and having a small issue with the alert() function.
I have this piece of code :

```
document.getElementById('picture').src="scene"+curScene+".png";
if(curScene!=0)
    alert(text);
```

The issue is that the browser executes the alert function before changing the image.Why is that? Isn't the code executed in order? Why does it jumps over lines?

I found something on this on google, but when I apply it to my script, it does't work.

Thank you!

Comment: The alert shows before the image has been loaded. Loading the image is asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code is asyncronous. Statements that take a long time to load like ajax or image loading execute in parallel.  If you really want to alert() after the image src is loaded then you should wrap that code in a callback such as onload event.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newImage = document.getElementById('picture').src="scene"+curScene+".png";
newImage.onload = function(){
  if(curScene != 0){
    alert('text');
  }
}
```